# Add minutes to epoch in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to get midnight date of actual timestamptz and add some minutes to it.
What's wrong with the following code?

```
SET TIMEZONE TO 'Europe/London';
SELECT 
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2023-10-29 00:00:00'::DATE + INTERVAL '1 minute' * 1439)::TIMESTAMPTZ) <>
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2023-10-29 00:00:00'::DATE)::TIMESTAMPTZ) + 60 * 1439
UNION
SELECT 
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2023-10-27 00:00:00'::DATE + INTERVAL '1 minute' * 1439)::TIMESTAMPTZ) <>
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2023-10-27 00:00:00'::DATE)::TIMESTAMPTZ) + 60 * 1439;
```

I'm getting false is 1st row and true in 2nd row. The results are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had to do with summer time. On 29th of october summer time is ending and thus the clock in that timezone is moved back one hour.

In the first statement of the second comparison

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2023-10-27 00:00:00'::DATE + INTERVAL '1 minute' * 1439)::TIMESTAMPTZ)
```

you first add the hours, and then convert to timezone, so the hour difference in summertime is not taken into consideration in your manual addition of 1439 minutes.

In the second part of the comparison

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2023-10-27 00:00:00'::DATE)::TIMESTAMPTZ) + 60 * 1439;
```

you first convert the begin time to the timezone, and then add 1439 minutes to the timestamp, and thus also triggering the hour reduction in summer time.

Thus the second comparison results in an hour difference in the two statements.

The first comparison has no summer time changes and thus are the statements the same.

Comment: How did I trigger hour reduction by addition  60 * 1439 to number? epoch is not utc?

Comment: in the first timestamp where you add time directly to the epoch, you get no summer time. It is only when you convert that epoch back to timestamp london/europe that the summertime comes into play.